# Adding checked attribute to selected input ajax

Tags: ajax, wordpress, input, call, checked

Made a ajax filter with custom taxonomy on WordPress, everything works fine but problem is that checkbox doesn't get checked attribute when click and new results are shown. I don't know what I'm missing here?

HTML

```
<div class="categories">
    <?php
        $cat_args = get_terms(array(
        'taxonomy' => 'position',
        'orderby' => 'name',
        ));

        $categories = $cat_args;

        foreach($categories as $cat) : ?>
        <label class="hotel-service block mb-2 font-montserrat text-altumTitle text-lg font-medium">
<input type="checkbox" value="yes" class="checkbox" data-category="<?php echo $cat->term_id ?>" href="<?php echo get_category_link($cat->term_id); ?>">&nbsp; <?php echo $cat->name; ?></label>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </div>
```

Ajax call

```
(function($) {
    
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '.hotel-service > input', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    
        var category = $(this).data('category');
    
        $.ajax({
        url: wpAjax.ajaxUrl,
        // filter here is handler for add_action callback function in ajax-filter.php
        data: { action: 'hotelService', category: category},
        type: 'post',
        success: function(result) {
            $('#response').html(result);
        },
        error: function(result) {
            console.warn(result);
        }
    
        });
    
    
    });
    });
    
    
    })(jQuery);
```

Comment: Are you saying that when the ajax action is done, `checkbox doesn't get checked attribute when click and new results are shown` ?

Comment: @Howard E yes exactly

Comment: Ajax actions happen after the document has loaded, so you need to add a condition for `$(window).on('ajaxcomplete'` to do anything after the ajax is done, or add something to your `success` callback.